# Regex to replace html script tag, except one type

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace

I need to replace all script tag (`<script></script>`) by blank, except a certain type.

I already have that working for all script tags.

```
var x = /<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi;

y.replace(x, "");
```

How do I replace all `<script>` except, for example, script tags with id attribute "xyz", `<script id="xyz">`?

Edit: Thanks for your tips, but I forgot to mention that i'm working over an ajax response!

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1)

Comment: This wouldn't be a good use of regex. You can iterate over all of the script tags and remove the ones that don't have a given id.

Comment: Walk the DOM and then `document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].id = 'xyz';`. Note that you can only have one id per page. Use `Element.className = 'xyz';` to assign the HTML class attribute.

Comment: How i get this work with ajax response? Walk the DOM is not an option, i think.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that once a `<script>` has made it to the *#document*, it's been interpreted so the code is there even if you remove it. You may want to create a *#document-fragment* to interpret the *HTML* and apply your desired transformation there, before inserting it into your main *#document*.

---

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` and `:not` to find nodes with exceptions and then perform some action on them

```
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('script:not(#xyz)'), i = elms.length;
while (i-->0) {
    elms[i].parentNode.removeChild(elms[i]);
}
```

Comment: 1+ But nitpicking, `i-->0` may seem an unexisting arrow operator. `i-- > 0`, `0 < i--` may be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This code will capture all `<script>` tags so that you can iterate (loop) over them.  I configured this one to remove them all, but you could easily wrap this in an if-condition.

Following the example ...

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i=0; i < all.length; i++) {
    var all_id = all[i].id;
    if (all_id!=="xyz") {
      all[i].parentNode.removeChild(all[i]);
    }
}
```

... slightly more readable ...

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i=0; i < all.length; i++) {
    var all_id = all[i].id;
    if (all_id==="xyz") {
      // DO NOTHING IF ID==="xyz"
    } else {
      all[i].parentNode.removeChild(all[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```js
console.group('All with [id] attr');
$('script').not('[id]').each(function() {
  console.log('Removed:', this);
  this.remove();
});
$('script').each(function() {
  console.log('Kept:', this);
});
console.groupEnd();

console.group('Only [id=test]');
$('script').not('[id=test]').each(function() {
  console.log('Removed:', this);
  this.remove();
});
$('script').each(function() {
  console.log('Kept:', this);
});
console.groupEnd();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="test"></script>
<script id></script>
<script></script>
```